Configuracion NAT Router CISCO 1941

Tengo este escenario en donde los host de lado interno de la red hacen a internet mediante la ip publica aplicando NAT, como se puede observar tengo un servidor con xampp instalado el cual un host desde la red externa puede acceder mediante la ip publica, me estoy topando con el detalle que si el host de la red interna como la 192.168.1.10 quiere ver la pagina web montada en el servidor xampp solo me la carga cuando ingreso la ip del servidor que es la 192.168.1.4, pero si pongo la ip publica no me carga, los clientes externos si pueden observar la pagina mediante la ip publica, solamente los host internos no
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
  ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
  ip nat inside

interface GigabitEthernet0/1
  ip address x.x.x.x 255.255.255.248
  ip nat outside

ip nat inside source static 192.168.1.4 189.195.132.78 route-map ROUTE_MAP

ip access-list extended ACL
  permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 host x.x.x.x

route-map ROUTE_MAP permit 10
  match ip address ACL

ip access-list standard LAN-TO-INTERNET
  permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255

ip nat inside source list LAN-TO-INTERNET interface GigabitEthernet0/1 overload

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 x.x.x.x(gateway ip publica)

